# creating Cascaded dropdowns(WinForm)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using below code to fill my combobox ,now `using`code is working and i am getting country combobox with country items,but If I write `using` code in `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` than `using` code doesn't work,why is that so ? and because of this i am not getting state dropdown based on country selected ,how it should be done?

```
public partial class RegPatient : Form
    {
        DBHandling db = new DBHandling();
        string cmbvalue="";
        public RegPatient()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
             using (DataTable dt = DBHandling.GetCountryDataTable())
            {
                comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(dt, null);
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "CountryName"; //column to show in comboBox
                comboBox1.ValueMember = "Code"; 
            }//here the table is disposed 
        }
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            //using code not working here          
        } 
    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (DataTable dt = DBHandling.GetStateDataTable(comboBox1.Text) )
        {
            // contine using dt
            comboBox2.DataSource = new BindingSource(dt, null);
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "ProvinceName"; 
           }//here the table is disposed 
    }   
    }
```

**Code for getting datatable country and state**

```
public static DataTable GetCountryDataTable()
        {
            DataTable countryTable = new DataTable();

            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=sonorepo.mdb")) //use your conn. string here
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT CountryName, Code FROM Country", con))
                    da.Fill(countryTable);
            }
            return countryTable;
        }
        public static DataTable GetStateDataTable(string countryCode)
        {
            DataTable stateTable = new DataTable();
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=sonorepo.mdb"))
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT ProvinceName FROM Province where Country='" + countryCode + "'", con))
                    da.Fill(stateTable);
            }
            return stateTable;
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you give that code that needs to be present in `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` and just in case can you please check if this event is getting fired?

Comment: Using disposes `DataTable` when it is being used as datasource for `comboBox`. Is that makes sense to use disposed object as datasource?

Comment: @Bharath I cheked it ,I dont know Why trigger is not getting fired

Comment: @SriramSakthivel After removing `using` also not getting desired output

Comment: @Durga Explain what is happening. *not getting desired output means*

Comment: @SriramSakthivel if I remove `using` keyword and write rest of the code in `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` not getting country values in combobox1

Comment: You mean `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` not fired or combobox not populated with values?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37579/discussion-between-durga-and-sriram-sakthivel)

Answer (score 0):

in the method  comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged  you cannot create a local  DataTable  and use it as the datasource. After your code leaves the using statement the  DataTable  will be destroyed, leaving  comboBox2  without a data source.

Leave out the using statement:

```
DataTable dt = DBHandling.GetStateDataTable(comboBox1.Text)
```

You are probably just copying a reference to an existing  DataTable. So why would you want to dispose it?

Comment: I removed using statement ,but regarding issue what is the solution

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged` event and double click on the ComboBox2 to create the event again and check if the event is getting fired.

If its ASP.Net application check if you have set `AutoPostBack` property

Comment: I did this for both combobox but still event is not getting fired

Comment: Dumb question! Is it a winform or a asp.net application?

Comment: It is WinForm application

Comment: I am sorry could not guess what the problem might be... try `TextChanged` event for the combobox or delete the control and create it from scratch